# How do custom and multilanguage messages errors on sails js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419928/how-to-define-error-message-in-sails-js), he explain the method for create a custom messages but not says how do messages with multi languages in the errors. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sails has built-in utility for application [internalization](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Internationalization) based on [i18-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n) package.

Usage is very simple. First you need to configure your locales in [`config/i18n`](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/anatomy/myApp/config/i18n.js.html) folder. Second you need to create translation files under [`config/locales`](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/anatomy/myApp/config/locales/_README.md.html) folder.

Then you can just use it:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        }
    },

    validation_messages: {
        name: {
            required: 'you_have_to_specify_a_name_or_else'
        }
    }  
};
```

And then in view actually translating:

```
<p>Validation Error: <%= __('you_have_to_specify_a_name_or_else') %>
```

If your views are not rendering on backend you can use `sails.__()` method for translating directly in the model.